# Which Azure service is most suited for (simple) docker compose configurations?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure

I want to run the [Eramba docker compose](https://github.com/eramba/docker) on Azure. I tried following a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) for Azure Container Instances, but the docker cli functions in this tutorial are retired.
The configuration exists of 3 services: MySQL, Redis, Eramba. Am I better off using Azure Container Apps or Container Instances? Or are there other services that might be easier, such as simply using a VM?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.